# Systemc - Rounding off sc_time to nearest 10th SC_NS

Tags: c++, systemc

I am trying to round off the sc_time to the nearest 10 nanoseconds. `/` is overloaded so it is possible to divide two `sc_time`. `*` is also overloaded with a `sc_time` and a `double` value. For this code, I am getting `6` and not `10`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include "systemc.h"

SC_MODULE(X)
{
    SC_CTOR(X)
    {
        SC_THREAD(a);

    }
    void a()
    {   
    sc_time t(6, SC_NS);
    sc_time t1(10, SC_NS);
    double v = (t / t1) *10;
    std::cout << "sc_time update:/ " << v << "\n";


    }
};

int sc_main( int , char* [] )
{
    sc_clock clock;
    X x("x");

    sc_start(1000, SC_NS);

    cout << "Program completed" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quick glance through the `sc_time` header https://github.com/systemc/systemc-2.3/blob/master/src/sysc/kernel/sc_time.h indicates it does its maths using doubles so it's not surprising that `6/10*10==6` you need to add an explicit round:

```
double v = round(t / t1) *10;
```